# Two recycler view inside a scroll view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I can use nested scroll view to have two recycler view but issue with that is recycler view is no more recycler view as it inflates all the view at once and if I add a on scroll listener to any recycler view then you will see all items are visible at once.

Is there any way where I can achieve scrollability of both recycler view at once.

Use Case:

I need to show scheduled events on top of history of events. I just want that both behaves as one big recycler view maintained individually. I don't mind showing all scheduled events before history of events.

```
 <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/pullToRefresh"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_meetings_above_divider"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inviteContactImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp_30"
        >
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/upcomingScheduledEvent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_history_above_divider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="8dp"
                android:background="#EEEEEE"/>
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recentEvents"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/noRecentEvents"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/px_32"
                    android:text="@string/find_your_colleagues_and_friends_to_chat"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/dp_14" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/id_startSearch"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/no_meeting_round_button_drawable"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/chat_now"
                    android:textColor="@color/action_bar_color"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show your code, please? So that, we can help you somehow.

Comment: Will share in a min.

Comment: @ZBorkala please check.

Comment: If you also provide a screenshot of the current result, that would be better.

Comment: Upcoming schedule event recylcer and recent view recycler are scrolling at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a heterogeneous recycler view with three views. First is the scheduled events which are always on top, then the separator and then the recent event views. Read more about multiple views in a recycler view or heterogeneous recycler view.